# AlmaLinux cannot install ffmpeg

Tags: linux, package-management, repository, ffmpeg

New install of AlmaLinux 8 (r8.7 (Stone Smilodon)).  I ran the following in preparation to install ffmpeg:

```
sudo dnf -y install https://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install yum-utils -y
sudo yum-config-manager --enable powertools
sudo dnf install --nogpgcheck https://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-8.noarch.rpm -y
sudo dnf install --nogpgcheck https://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/el/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-8.noarch.rpm -y
```

When I run the final `sudo dnf install ffmpeg ffmpeg-devel`, I get the following error:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:22:38 ago on Tue 25 Apr 2023 11:48:30 AM MDT.
No match for argument: ffmpeg
Error: Unable to find a match: ffmpeg
```

I have installed and run ffmpeg with no issue on previous machines and on other flavour of 'Nix, but this one stumps me.  I ran an `dnf repolist` and got this:

```
repo id                                                           repo name
appstream                                                         AlmaLinux 8 - AppStream
baseos                                                            AlmaLinux 8 - BaseOS
dell-omsa-indep                                                   Dell OMSA repository - Hardware independent
dell-omsa-specific                                                Dell OMSA repository - Hardware specific
dell-system-update_dependent                                      dell-system-update_dependent
dell-system-update_independent                                    dell-system-update_independent
elevate                                                           ELevate
epel                                                              Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64
extras                                                            AlmaLinux 8 - Extras
influxdata                                                        InfluxData Repository - Stable
influxdb                                                          InfluxDB Repository
powertools                                                        AlmaLinux 8 - PowerTools
```

So the repository is present and correct.

I do not know where else to check.  This should be simple.  Can someone please help me get this installed?

Comment: `So the repository is present and correct` - no, it's not. The rpmfusion repos are not listed. Something went wrong during their installation step.

Comment: yeah.  i think i was console-blind from too many hours on task.  IIRC, i manually added the repos and went from there.  i got super busy and haven't been back here since then.  apologies.

Answer (score 2):

The following steps worked for me:

```
dnf config-manager --set-enabled powertools
dnf install --nogpgcheck https://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-$(rpm -E %rhel).noarch.rpm -y
dnf install --nogpgcheck https://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/el/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-$(rpm -E %rhel).noarch.rpm -y
dnf install ffmpeg
```

You don't even need epel. Just the powertools and rpmfusion repos are enough for ffmpeg.